# Voronoi approach to making districts while also using a multilinestring

Tags: r, r-sf, voronoi

I have a spatial objects with multiple points (buildings) on a map. What I wanted to do is divide an area based on the nearest point. The calculated Voronoi looks quite promising, but has some strange aspects if you know the "real world". For example a small part of a district is also at the other side of a river because of the closeness (surprise).

What I want to do is combine this with a multi linestring which contains rivers, railroads. What I want to do either end the district at this line OR add a penalty for 'crossing' it. Is anyone able to shed light on the problem, or possible suggest an alternative voronoi method that works?